# Вывод данных по очереди в цикле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Есть выражения в python3.

```
ips = ['10.10.10.98', '10.10.10.99']
for ip in ips: 
    print(ip)
```

> ```
> 10.11.3.98 
> 10.11.3.99 #Вывод ip
> ```

Как по очереди выводит эти ip?

Например: для добавления этих ip(по очереди) в текстовый файл.
Сейчас он добавляет только последний ip 10.11.3.99.

Comment: Если добавляет только последний, значит в коде написано добавлять только последний. Покажи код, который пишет в файл.

Comment: Как поочередно передать эти ip в запрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ips = ['10.10.10.98', '10.10.10.99']
with open("ips.txt", mode = "w") as file: # открываем файл
    for ip in ips: # проходим в цикле по списку и пишем в файл
        file.write(ip + "\n")
```

Comment: Если мне нужно поочередно передать эти ip в запрос, как это сделать?)

Comment: Например, вы можете идти в цикле по списку и по очереди передавать очередной элемент в какую-либо функцию. Т.е., вместо `file.write(ip + "\n")` будет `some_function(ip)`.

Answer (score 8):

Можно ещё через `print` сделать запись в файл. У него есть параметр `file`, который задает куда `print` будет выводить строки, и, по умолчанию, равен `sys.stdout`. Но можно сделать вывод в файл:

```python
ips = ['10.10.10.98', '10.10.10.99']

with open('ips.txt', 'w') as f:
    for ip in ips:
        print(ip, file=f)
```

В этом случае `\n` можно не добавлять, поскольку `print` сам его добавляет в конец строки. Это можно изменить через параметр `end`.

Comment: Вообще ```print``` в _Python_ прямо-таки волшебная вещь, ибо можно сделать и так: ```with open('ips.txt', 'w') as f: print(*['10.10.10.98', '10.10.10.99'], sep='\n', file=f)```

Answer (score 4):

Можно из списка составить строку и её записать в файл:

```
ips = ['10.10.10.98', '10.10.10.99']
with open("ips.txt", mode="w") as f:
    file.write("\n".join(ips))
```

Answer (score 1):

Раз уж здесь получился некий "обзор" методов сохранения, позволю и себе некоторое дополнение.
**Первое.** Из приведенных выше вариантов сохранения самый медленный на больших файлах вариант с `file.write("\n".join(ips))`. И он будет просто "жрать" память при объединении все в одну гигантскую строчную переменную. Два других - одинаковые по скорости и результату.
**Второе.** Обычно сохраняют данные в файле чтобы позже самому прочесть или передать внешнему пользователю.
Если предполагается первый вариант - "сам записал потом сам читаю", то много эффективней сохранение сериализацией с использованием модулей pickle, json, shelve.

```
import pickle
ips = ['10.10.10.98', '10.10.10.99']
with open('ips.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(ips, f)
```

что позволит позже "восстановить" весь список в переменную, не задумываясь о том, как вы будете парсить строки в ips:

```
with open('ips.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    ips = pickle.load(f)
print(ips)
```

json - как правило медленнее, однако сохраняет в практически стандартном формате json, который человечнее - его можно открыть и понять - что же там сохранилось.  Есть еще несколько библиотек сериализации со своими особенностями, такие как: [jsonpickle](http://jsonpickle.github.io/), [simplejson](https://simplejson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [demjson](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson/). Все они используют формат json, и по своему расширяют возможности стандартного [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)-модуля, включеного в дистрибутив Python.

Самый быстрый, но зависящий от версии языка сериализации добиваются встроенным модулем [`marshal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/marshal.html). Код практически тот же:

```
import marshal
ips = ['10.10.10.98', '10.10.10.99']
with open('ips.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    marshal.dump(ips, f)


with open('ips.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    ips = marshal.load(f)
print(ips)


['10.10.10.98', '10.10.10.99']
```